# Confluent Monitoring Interceptors inside Docker container for confluent-kafka-dotnet

Tags: c#, docker, apache-kafka, .net-core, confluent-platform

I try to run example app using `confluent-kafka-dotnet` inside Docker container, and it works fine with producer and consumer. But to get stream processor in confluent control center, need setup [Confluent Monitoring Interceptors](https://docs.confluent.io/current/control-center/docs/installation/clients.html#installing-interceptors). Need add plugin to config:

```
var config = new Dictionary<string, object> 
{ 
      { "bootstrap.servers", "kafka:9092" },
      { "plugin.library.paths", "monitoring-interceptor" }
};
```

From manual I download libs for MacOs and it works fine, but when I try run this inside Docker container I get error:

```
System.ArgumentException: dlopen() failed: monitoring-interceptor.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (plugin monitoring-interceptor)
at Confluent.Kafka.Impl.SafeConfigHandle.Set(String name, String value)
at Confluent.Kafka.Producer.<>c__DisplayClass23_0.<.ctor>b__3(KeyValuePair`2 kvp)
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)
```

I try install `confluent-librdkafka-plugins` from installation manual for Linux, but get same problem.

Comment: Where are you putting the `so` file in the container? Or are you able to find it yourself after installing that package?

Comment: try specifying an absolute path to monitoring-interceptor.so. if you've put the library in a standard location, try running `ldconfig`.  Given you see this error, librdkafka has been loaded successfully, suggesting a path issue (rather than a dependency issue, which could also cause this error). you could try running `ldd monitoring-interceptor.so` to check for that though as well anyway.